WPF displays a white blank window when using Show()
I'm working on a trivia kahoot style game, where the client is based on the WPF framework (hello to all fellow magshimim students with the same issue)
When loading the game window, which is supposed to request and display questions from the server, the window shows up blank. There are no compilation errors or runtime exceptions, and I when clicking on the minimized window in the taskbar it doesn't open.
        public GameQuestionWindow(Communicator communicator, MenuWindow menu, int timePerQuestion, int questionsLeft, Window prevWindow)
        {
            this.Show();
            InitializeComponent();
            prevWindow.Close();

            m_communicator = communicator;
            m_questionsLeft = questionsLeft;
            m_menuWindow = menu;

            m_mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            m_mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Client;component/Audio/tick.mp3"));

            time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timePerQuestion);
            timer = new DispatcherTimer();

            gameLoop();
        }

I've tried performing this.Show() after the initialization instead, or using ShowDialog(), but the problem with the latter is that none of the background game logic is executed and the thread is halted, while the window is once again blank.
This is how the window is created:
            if (serverResp.getCode() == 150)
            {
                shouldStop = true;
                GameQuestionWindow window = new GameQuestionWindow(this.communicator, this.menuWindow, answerTimeout, answerAmount, this);
            }

shouldStop is for a background refresh thread and is irrelevant.
I cannot put window.Show() after the constructor since all game logic is executed on the main thread in from the constructor as shown previously, meaning if Show() is called after the constructor returns, it'll only be after the game is done, as long as the calling window isn't closed before, which it is.
In the visual studio XAML designer the game window is shown without problem.
The window shown before the game

The blank game window


I tried it on a test project and it seemed to work on mine. There may be an exception that's being thrown and you are not catching. Verify it can resolve all it's resources. Do you have some resource files that may not resolve at runtime? I would start removing elements to single out the trouble if it's not apparent.

What is gameLoop();?

You mentioned that all your game logic runs on the main thread, I suppose inside the gameLoop. As a result, your main thread (= the UI thread) is constantly busy and has no time to render your window, react to user input etc. (It is not about time, it is that your main thread is stuck inside the loop and cannot do any other work while it is in there.)
One solution is to run your gameLoop in a background thread. I suppose you know how to do that, as you mentioned using a background thread for other tasks. For the parts of your game logic that must be run on the UI thread, you can use Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(...) to schedule code to run on the UI thread.
If your game logic contains waiting on stuff (like a timer, a http request or reading a file) another solution is making gameLoop async. That way, your code could run on the main thread and the main thread could still do the necessary UI stuff while the game logic is waiting.
